# Moves left too fast, Doesn't move right at all

Tags: java, graphics2d, rectangles

This one has me stumped.  I have no idea what is actually causing the problem, but I will try to provide as much relevant information as I can.  Please ask if you have any questions.

The `advance()` method is called about once every 0.0025 seconds, which is also the value of `elapsedTime`.

```
private int speed = 1;

public void advance(float elapsedTime) {
    rectangle.x = (int) (rectangle.x - speed * elapsedTime);
}
```

It the x coordinate shifts to the left way too fast, even if I set my speed to 0.0000001.  However, Whenever I try to move it to the right:

```
public void advance(float elapsedTime) {
    rectangle.x = (int) (rectangle.x + speed * elapsedTime);
}
```

It does not move at all.

Any ideas?  I am stumped!

Comment: edit in your function call

Comment: Can you post the code in which `advance()` is called?

Comment: you should output the value of `elapsedTime` to make sure it's non-zero. Also, output the value of `rectangle.x + speed * elapsedTime` before and after the conversion to `int`, to make sure it has nothing to do with your truncation (with `elapsedTime` values that small, I imagine you are just truncating off any change you make to `rectangle.x`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the rectangles coordinates are stored as ints, so they can only change, at minimum, by 1 at a time. Since draw runs so often, when moving to the left, it still moves very fast, because it can't move at less than 1 pixel at once.

The reason it doesn't move at all to the right is because of rounding. When casting to an int, the double is rounded down. So if your position is 5, and you try to add 0.00001, and then cast it to an int, your position ends up still being 5. If you were to subtract 0.000001, then it would be rounded down to 4, which is why moving to the left works.

Comment: hmmm i like ur thinking. lemme check it out